# Solve the nonlinear system with three equations and three variables $x,y,\lambda$.

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

$\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-y_A)^2}} + \dfrac{x-x_B}{\sqrt{(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2}} = 2x\lambda
\\\\
\dfrac{y - y_A}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-y_A)^2}} + \dfrac{y-y_B}{\sqrt{(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2}} = 2y\lambda
\\\\
x^2+y^2=R^2
\end{cases}$

How can I solve the above system for $x,y,\lambda$?

$y_A,x_B,y_B$ and $R$ are given constants.

I tried squaring and adding the two first lines, but got nothing. Substituting the third line into the two first lines also didn't solve it for me.

Comment: I have the feeling that this comes from a Lagrange multiplier calculation. May be, it could be good to precise he problem (in case there is another formulation of it)

Comment: Although there is a context, for which the answer provided by Israel could solve it, I need help in solving the system.

Answer (score 0):

If the line segment  $AB$ intersects the circle, let $P$ be any of the points where it does.  If it doesn't intersect the circle, you want the point $P$ on the circle where a ray of light from $A$ will reflect to $B$.  This has the property that the ray from the centre of the circle through $P$ bisects the angle $APB$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve the system that I need, so I cannot accept it.